# Leveraging browser cache with IIS7.5 for javascripts and css

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-7.5, browser-cache

I'm working on a Web Project (ASP.NET MVC 2 but it doesn't matter for this question) I'd like to fine-tune performance.

Setting the clientCache settings in order to let static content be cached is working
perfectly with images BUT, Internet Explorer 8 (or 9) is still performing a GET ("if-modified-since")
for javascripts and css (so a 304 is responded by IIS).

I'd like to avoid IE to perform a useless GET for static resources already in cache.

I've verifified this with the Network Capture tool from IE9 Development Tools and with Fiddler. 
Chrome is working like expected, getting javascript / css from the cache.

The setting I'm adding to my web.config is:

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <staticContent> 
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="165.00:00:00" /> 
        </staticContent> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

I doubt the source of the issue is the dynamic compression I enabled on IIS for application/x-javascript MIME type.
I left default settings so no cache headers are sent to the client for gzipped content.